# Failed to setup dotNet certificate on mac by all means

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I am trying to run the Dotnet version 6 app on macOS latest version
I searched everywhere, it was always required to install the certificate although I had a valid one.

`"Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.\nTo generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.\nFor more information on configuring HTTPS see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054`

what I did
1- Deleted the keychain altogether many times.
2- Restart, shutdown, and reinstall the SDK and visual studio .
3- test for the certificate `A valid HTTPS certificate is already present .`
4- I did `dotnet dev-certs https --clean` then `dotnet dev-certs https`  then `dotnet dev-certs https --trust`  and `A valid HTTPS certificate is already present.`

and still failed to run the MVC web app. the error reoccurs.
Any idea will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the `KeyChain` Deleting the certificate from the keychain and then `Run without Debugging` from visual studio code until it needs the keychain password. then it works

Comment: I am struggling with my configuration on a Mac as well. I can't get the iOS simulator to connect to the webapi. What does your appsettings.Development.json look like? I am trying to connect directly to the keystore using the Kestrel settings, but with no luck.

Comment: @lcj the default

Comment: I had this configuration, what did you have: 
        "Source": "Store",
        "StoreLocation": "CurrentUser",
        "StoreName": "My",
        "Subject": "CN=localhost",
        "AllowInvalid": true

Comment: sorry, i was testing the c# with mac but I was not comfortable so I left it altogether . I think it is more suitable for windows.